# Garbage values on TChart Axis

Tags: c#-4.0, teechart

I've been working with TChart version 4.11 for .net 4.0
Everything is fine with charts rendered using this new version in C#, except some garbage at the begining of left and bottom axis?
I am not getting why its happening?
If anyone have used this newer version and has faced the same thing, please let me know?

thanks in advance,
Kapil

Comment: -1: Poorly worded, too little detail to answer, no example code.  Not a useful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG...it was so simple. I figured out that axis labels need value format which was being set to exponential format, and was resulting in garbage looking figueres for some of the values, especially starting values. On setting appropriate, its looking cool now.